# Detecting charcater encoding for wp-config.php file

Tags: php, wp-config

[image]I have encountered the following problem as can be seen in the file attached.

The story is as follows:-

I have created a subdomain on my main domain and when I am trying to install WordPress on the subdomain which I created, as I am trying to edit the wp-config.php file in the Cpanel and clicked the edit option the error shown in the file appeared and the bar in the center is continuously progressing saying "detecting character encoding for "wp-config.php".

I have contacted my hosting provider for it's solution, but they said to ask your developer. I have done all the tasks myself so I get stucked up.

I have also gone to Cpanel and Cloudflare communities as well and they have asked to contact my contact your license provider.

Those guys at my domain registrar are not very helpful, that's why I am here.

The second image attached shows all the relevant data that might be helpful.

So, please have a deep look into my issue and provide me a solution asap.

Thanks and Regards,

Muhammad Aquilur Rahman[![Image 1 is for all of the relevant data on my storage of Cpanel ][Image 2 is showing the error encountered.]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzVec.png)

[image]

Comment: Well, how about just using an FTP client to download the config file, edit and save it locally, then upload back using that FTP client.. Code editor software would likely be able to detect the character encoding and possibly change it (to the correct one, if it isn't already correct) for you. But this is not a WordPress-specific issue and instead, it just happened in the context of WordPress.

Comment: Hey Sally, Thanks a lot. Will you please guide me as to how can I solve this issue? I am not a WordPress developer and did not know about coding. Give me some useful links for using the FTP client from my Cpanel. An article or YouTube video. Thanks once again